# Read values from multiple JSON files in terraform

Tags: json, terraform

The task here is to deploy multiple applications on a Shared App Gateway in Azure using Terraform. I have come across using input.json file in terraform, but since I'm working on a Shared App Gateway, which will have multiple listeners, frontends, probes and backends, how will I be able to extract data from multiple JSON files.

For example, my file structure is as follows:
App1.json
App2.json
App3.json

Now the content of the App1.json file would be something like:

```
{
    "App1": [
        {
            "listener": "${App1}-listener",
            "probe": "${App1}-probe",
            "backend": "{App1}-backend"
        }
    ]
}
```

and so on.

Now, how do I use the for_each loop to deploy a shared App Gateway with multiple listeners, probes and backends?

Comment: Show us your terraform code

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you need a way to "import" an object from a JSON file into Terraform. You can achieve this by doing:

```
locals {
  json_data = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/data.json"))
}
```

In your case, you may do something like this to then be able to iterate with a for_each on you apps:

```
locals {
  app_1 = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/app_1.json"))
  app_2 = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/app_2.json"))
  app_3 = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/app_3.json"))
  # apps has the combined structure of the three JSON files
  apps  = merge(app1, app2, app3)
}
```